# Let $(G, *)$ be a group and let $\{g,h\}$ be a subset of $G$. Prove that $(g*h)^{-1}=h^{-1}*g^{-1 }$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $(G, *)$ be a group and let $\{g,h\}$ be a subset of $G$.  Prove that $(g*h)^{-1}=h^{-1}*g^{-1}$.

I know that I should show that $X*Y=Y*X=e$.
But I don't know how to calculate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know there is a unique inverse to every element $a\in G$ then you know there is a unique inverse to the element $gh\in G$.

Then let's try $(gh)^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-1}$ as a guess candidate!

Note that $(gh)(h^{-1}g^{-1})=(h^{-1}g^{-1})(gh)=e$. As inverse is unique, it follows that $h^{-1}g^{-1}$ is indeed the inverse of $gh$!!

Answer (score 1):

You are asking why the inverse of $gh$ is equal to $h^{-1}g^{-1}$. As you write, you need to check that

$$(gh)(h^{-1}g^{-1}) = e,$$

and $$(h^{-1}g^{-1})gh = e.$$

Take the first one. I can put the brackets like I want to due to the associative property, so

$$(gh)(h^{-1}g^{-1}) = g(hh^{-1})g^{-1}.$$

Do you see where to go with this? Since $h^{-1}$ is the inverse of $h$, you can rewrite $hh^{-1}$.